# Gmail API get list "An error occurred: { "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Bad Request" } " in PHP

Tags: api, gmail

I am trying to get mail list using php library. It was working before , but now it show the following error :

> An error occurred: { "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description":
>   "Bad Request" }
>
> array(0) { }

Code:

```
function getList($lastsynctime='') {       
  // Get the API client and construct the service object.
  $client = $this->getClient();
  $service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

  // $newTime = strtotime('-15 minutes');
  if ($lastsynctime =='') {        
    $newTime = strtotime('-60 day');
    $after = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $newTime));
  }else{
    $after = strtotime($lastsynctime);
  }

  // Print the labels in the user's account.
  $userId = 'me';
  $pageToken = NULL;
  $messages = array();
  $opt_param = array();
  do {
    try {
      if ($pageToken) {
        $opt_param['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
      }

      $opt_param['q'] = "from:example@gmail.com after:$after";

      $messagesResponse = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages($userId, $opt_param);
  echo "<pre>";var_dump($messagesResponse);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
      print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
  } while ($pageToken);


  return $messagesResponse;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well! As your code was working before and you haven't change anything. Then i think the problem is not in you code.

You can check your **Connected apps and sites** settings under your gmail **My Account** menu to make sure your app is there.

If the app is there but yet not working then you need to delete the app and regenerate your **client secret key**. Because your client secret may get expired.

Comment: Happy to know that.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in different API (Google Search Console).

Try visiting https://myaccount.google.com/security#connectedapps from your Gmail account.

See if `Drive Testing Key` shows up under `Apps with account access`. If it doesn't, then as @Mahbubul Islam mentioned, you'll need to create the credentials again.